# Unexpected non-constant std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time, initializer-list

I was toying a little bit with the indices trick to see where I could go to with and came across a strange error... First, the plain not-so-old indices:

```
template<std::size_t...>
struct indices {};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices>
struct make_indices:
    make_indices<N-1, N-1, Indices...>
{};

template<std::size_t... Indices>
struct make_indices<0, Indices...>:
    indices<Indices...>
{};
```

I created a compile-time array class derived from a `std::initializer_list` and had it indexable (assume that [N3471](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3471.html) is support by your compiler. It will be in the next standard anyway). Here it is:

```
template<typename T>
struct array:
    public std::initializer_list<T>
{
    constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> values):
        std::initializer_list<T>(values)
    {}

    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t n)
        -> T
    {
        return this->begin()[n];
    }
};
```

So, I tried to create a function that returns a copy of an `array` after having added 1 to each of its members:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... I>
auto constexpr add_one(const array<T>& a, indices<I...>)
    -> const array<T>
{
    return { (a[I]+1)... };
}
```

And to finish with the code, here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr array<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    constexpr auto b = add_one(a, make_indices<a.size()>());

    return 0;
}
```

I did not think that code would compile anyway, but I am quite surprised by the error message (Here is the [ideone](http://ideone.com/gBRfhg) code):

```
In function 'int main()':
error: 'const smath::array<int>{std::initializer_list<int>{((const int*)(& const int [3]{2, 3, 4})), 3u}}' is not a constant expression
```

So, could someone explain to me what exactly is not constant enough for the compiler in the above code?

**EDIT:** Follow-ups for that question

- [Is it legal to declare a constexpr std::initializer_list object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16063123/1364752)
- [Confusion about constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16057690/1364752)

Comment: A *brace-or-equal* initializer is not an expression and can as such never be a constant expression, is what I think is the issue here.

Comment: In fact, Clang 3.2 rejects even the initialization of `a`

Comment: @AndyProwl I know, Clang does not support N3471, that's why :)

Comment: @Morwenn: Oh, that explains :)

Comment: @Xeo Err, would you care to explain a little bit more? I am trying to understand but am quite lost in the details when I try to think about it.

Comment: @Morwenn: Here, `{ (a[I]+1)... }` is not an expression. It is a language construct used for initialization, but it is not itself an expression (although individual elements of the initializer list are). Since it is not an expression, it cannot be a *constant* expression. This is what I think Xeo meant.

Comment: Exactly what @Andy says. Really, if you want a compile-time array, just use `std::array` with the augmentations, which can be initialized through aggregate-initialization.

Comment: @Xeo The fun part was to try to create a compile-time array without having to specify its length and to be able to use it without some heavy template syntax (it's just for fun, I do not really care any further). That part was ok, but compile-time operations still seem a bit too much to handle :p

Comment: @Morwenn If it's just about creating "a compile-time array w/o having to specify its length", then why not use something like `template < typename T, typename... TT > std::array < T, sizeof...(TT)+1 > create_array(T&& p, TT&&... pp); auto my_array = create_array<int>(1,2,3,4,5);`

Comment: @DyP Well, `auto` does the trick, but the type still contains the size in the end. Moreover, we can't use the curly-brace-initializer syntax anymore unless we put another pair of enclosing braces, which is not really nice (unless N3526 makes its way to the standard and to the compilers).

Comment: @Morwenn Well the type has to include the size - if you do not want to impose a hard-coded size restriction (e.g. fixed-size 1000 element array, filling only the first n elements). The compiler has to know the `sizeof` of the type, and declaration/definition (requiring a complete type) must be before initialisation. Another way would be to use inheritance and bind a temporary to a `const&`, like `array<int> const& myArr = make_array<int>(1,2,3,4,5);`.

Comment: @DyP Actually, the fun thing with `std::initializer_list` is that it has a `constexpr` constructor. Therefore, it knows its own size at compile-time without it being specified in the type - hence my choice of inheriting from it -. But the underlying array being implementation-defined, I have no idea how it is handled :)

Comment: @Morwenn Ah now I get it... dirty and I like it :D But there's another problem: `initializer_list` itself is not a literal type (does not have to be, i.e. AFAIK there's no guarantee). `constexpr` objects must be of literal type [dcl.constexpr]/9 and your `array` isn't a literal type because it inherits of a non-literal type. You can also try to define a `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> mylist;` - fails for the same reason. It is also forbidden for `constexpr` ctors to have non-literal-type parameters [dcl.constexpr]/4.

Comment: @DyP Well, i guess that's okay even if it is not a literal type since N3471 mandates that `std::initializer_list`'s functions should be `constexpr` (adopted for C++14). GCC already implements it, Clang does not. Maybe it's ok as long as literal types are used in the initializer list; well, actually, I'm not sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28331/discussion-between-dyp-and-morwenn)

Answer (score 1):

From: the man himself
http://www.stroustrup.com/sac10-constexpr.pdf

Specifically:
 its return type, and the types of its parameters (if any), are literal
types (see x2.2). For concreteness, literal types include bool,
int, or double;
 its body is a compound statement of the form
{ return expr; }
where expr is such that if arbitrary constant expressions of
appropriate types are substituted for the parameters in expr, then
the resulting expression is a constant expression as deﬁned in
introductory paragraph of x2. The expression expr is called a
potential constant expression.