# Confusion about constant expressions involving std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, initializer-list, constant-expression

This is some kind of follow-up for [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023262/unexpected-non-constant-stdinitializer-list) and deals about a little part of it. As with the previous topic, let's consider that our compiler has `constexpr` functions for `std::initializer_list` and `std::array`. Now, let's go straight to the point.

[This works](http://ideone.com/uqNVFs):

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> a = {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
    constexpr int a0 = a[0];
    constexpr int a1 = a[1];
    constexpr int a2 = a[2];
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a0, a1, a2 };
}
```

[This does not](http://ideone.com/OOP0rL):

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> a = {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };
}
```

It crashes with this error:

```
error: 'const std::initializer_list<int>{((const int*)(&<anonymous>)), 3u}' is not a constant expression
```

Even though I read some papers about `constexpr` and constant expressions meanwhile, this behaviour still does not make any sense for me. How come the first example is considered a valid constant expression and not the second one? I would welcome any explanation so that I can rest in peace afterwards.

**NOTE:** I will precise it right away, Clang will not be able to compile the first snippet since it does not implement the `constexpr` library additions that are planned for C++14. I used GCC 4.7.

**EDIT:** Ok, here comes the big example to show what is rejected and what is not:

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

constexpr int foo = 42;
constexpr int bar() { return foo; }
struct eggs { int a, b; };

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> a = {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
    constexpr int a0 = a[0];
    constexpr int a1 = a[1];
    constexpr int a2 = a[2];

    // From Xeo and Andy tests
    constexpr std::array<int, 1> a = { bar() }; // OK
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> b = {{ a[0], a[1], a[2] }}; // OK
    std::initializer_list<int> b = { a[0], a[1], a[2] }; // OK
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a0, a1, a2 }; // OK
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { foo }; // OK
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> c = { bar() }; // ERROR
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a[0], a[1], a[2] }; // ERROR

    // From Matheus Izvekov and Daniel Krügler
    constexpr eggs good = { 1, 2 }; // OK
    constexpr std::initializer_list<eggs> bad = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }; // ERROR
    constexpr std::initializer_list<eggs> bad2 = { good, good }; // ERROR
}
```

Comment: How about "GCC has a bug"? :) (Not saying it has one, just a possibility.) And really, you should be able to test this without the `constexpr` additions by writing your own analogues. Also, what about `constexpr std::array<int, 3> b = {{ a[0], a[1], a[2] }};`?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ideone.com/56iP0Y) helps narrowing down the issue

Comment: @Xeo Whatever I do with array seems to work fine (including your example, and Andy ones with only `std::arrays` instead of `std::initializer_list`). It seems that the problem only occurs with `std::initializer_list` at compile time. I did not manage to reproduce it without `constexpr` or with `std::array`.

Comment: @Xeo So, yeah, I want to believe it is a GCC bug, but generally speaking, I would rather be sure it does not come from my understanding of the language :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what is going on here:

```
 constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };
```

`a[0]` of type `const int&` implicitly converts to a temporary of type `const int`.
Then g++ converts it to `const int*` to pass into the `initializer_list` private constructor.
In the last step it takes address of a temporary, so it is not a constant expression.

The problem is in implicit conversion to const int. Example:

```
constexpr int v = 1;
const int& r = v; // ok
constexpr int& r1 = v; // error: invalid initialization of reference of
                       // type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const int’
```

The same behavior is in clang.

I think this conversion is legal, nothing says the opposite.

About `const int&` to `const int` conversion, [expr] paragraph 5:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” , the type is
>   adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates
>   the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is
>   an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

The result of `a[0]` expression is the temporary xvalue of type `const int` in that case.

About implicit conversions in constexpr initializer, [dcl.constexpr] paragraph 9:

> ... Each implicit conversion used in converting the initializer
>   expressions and each constructor call used for the initialization
>   shall be one of those allowed in a constant expression.

About taking address of temporary, [expr.const] paragraph 2:

> ...an invocation of a constexpr function with arguments that, when
>   substituted by function invocation substitution, do not
>   produce a constant expression; [ Example:
>
> ```
> constexpr const int* addr(const int& ir) { return &ir; } // OK
> static const int x = 5;
> constexpr const int* xp = addr(x); // OK: (const int*)&(const int&)x is an
>                                    // address contant expression
> constexpr const int* tp = addr(5); // error, initializer for constexpr variable
>                                    // not a constant expression;
>                                    // (const int*)&(const int&)5 is not a
>                                    // constant expression because it takes
>                                    // the address of a temporary
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: The private ctor is not called with the elements you pass, it's called with a pointer to an *array* that is initialized from the elements you pass, and a size or a pointer to the end.

Comment: I actually submitted [a bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56991) to GCC. One of the guys manages to have g++ reject another example that does not involve any reference.

Comment: I point mostly at `const int&` to `const int` conversion, which causes such behavior and seems to be legal. First example shows the conversion in the raw. Part about ctor is to explain error message only.

Answer (score 2):

**Your examples are all ill-formed.**

***tl/dr:** The initializer is non-constant because it refers to a different temporary each time the function is evaluated.*

The declaration:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a0, a1, a2 };
```

creates a temporary array of type `const int [3]` (C++11 *[dcl.init.list]p5*), then binds the `std::initializer_list<int>` object to that temporary as if by binding a reference to it (C++11 *[dcl.init.list]p6*).

Now, by C++11 *[expr.const]p4*,

> For a literal constant expression of array or class type, each subobject [...] shall have been initialized by a constant expression. [...] An *address constant expression* [...] evaluates to the address of an object with **static storage duration**.

Since `b` has automatic storage duration, when the `std::initializer_list<int>` object binds to the `const int [3]` temporary, the temporary is also given automatic storage duration, so the initialization of `b` is *not* a constant expression because it refers to the address of an object that does not have static storage duration. So the declaration of `b` is ill-formed.

**Why GCC accepts some of the `constexpr` `std::initializer_list` objects**

In cases where the initializer is suitably trivial, GCC (and Clang) promote the array to global storage rather than creating a new temporary each time around. However, in GCC, this implementation technique leaks through to the language semantics -- GCC treats the array as having static storage duration, and accepts the initialization (as either an accidental or deliberate extension to the C++11 rules).

**Workaround (Clang only)**

You can make your examples valid by giving the `std::initializer_list<int>` objects static storage duration:

```
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b = { a0, a1, a2 };
```

This in turn gives static storage duration to the array temporary, which makes the initialization be a constant expression.

Using Clang and libc++ (with `constexpr` added to libc++'s `<array>` and `<initializer_list>` in the appropriate places), this tweak of adding `static` is sufficient for your examples to be accepted.

Using GCC, the examples are still rejected, with diagnostics such as:

```
<stdin>:21:61: error: ‘const std::initializer_list<int>{((const int*)(& _ZGRZ4mainE1c0)), 1u}’ is not a constant expression
```

Here, `_ZGRZ4mainE1c0` is the mangled name of the lifetime-extended array temporary (with static storage duration), and we can see that GCC is implicitly calling the (private) `initializer_list<int>(const int*, size_t)` constructor. I am not sure why GCC is still rejecting this.