# Is it legal to declare a constexpr initializer_list object?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, initializer-list, constexpr

As a question that came up during the discussion of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16023262/420683):

Is it legal, maybe with [N3471](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3471.html), to declare a `constexpr std::initializer_list` object? Example:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> my_list{};
```

---

Why I think it may not be legal: `initializer_list` would have to be a literal type; but are there any guarantees that it is a literal type?

Citations from N3485.

[dcl.constexpr]/9:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and shall be initialized.

literal types requirements, [basic.types]/10, sub-bullet class types:

> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - every constructor call and full-expression in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (if any) is a constant expression (5.19),
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

---

Bonus points ;) for answering if

```
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> my_list = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is legal (with references). Though I think this is covered by the above + [dcl.init.list]/5

Comment: Just to repeat what I said in the chat: I don't really get the point of making `std::initializer_list` functions `constexpr` (N3741) if we can't legally write the last example.

Comment: Another problem is the initialization. Common implementation uses pointers to access its underlying temporary array. If the array does not have static storage duration, initialization of the pointers [makes the whole initialization not a constant expression](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6.2). However, the storage duration of a temporary [seems not to be defined yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47945299/5376789).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** The situation got a bit more complicated after the resolution of [CWG DR 1684](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1684) removed the requirement quoted below. Some more information can be found in [this discussion on the std-discussion mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/aA3BsR4ZuoE/discussion) and in the related question [Why isn't `std::initializer_list` defined as a literal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27496004/420683)

---

[decl.constexpr]/8:

> A constexpr specifier for a non-static member function that is not a constructor declares that member function to be const (9.3.1). [...] The class of which that function is a member shall be a literal type (3.9).

Therefore, the changes of N3471 guarantee `std::initializer_list` will be a literal type.

---

Note the `constexpr` ctor alone doesn't require `std::initializer_list` to be a literal type, see [dcl.constexpr]/4+8. Side note: An object of non-literal type with `constexpr` ctor can be initialized during *constant initialization* [basic.start.init]/2] (part of *static initialization*, performed before any *dynamic initialization*).

Comment: I found this answer some hours after posting the question - wondering what use would be a `constexpr` ctor in a non-literal type.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything—is `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> my_list = {1,2,3,4,5};` legal or not in C++14?

Comment: @ChristopherC Sorry, it seems this requires a new investigation: The resolution of [CWG DR 1684](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1684) removed the quoted passage from the C++14 Standard. I cannot find any other hints that `std::initializer_list` is required to be a literal type at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!—these spec papers are still very cryptic to me. Using my C++14 + Clang 3.5 environment, I can see that all the methods from `std::initializer_list` are constexpr, so I thought the definition above had to be legal somehow, but it complains about the literal type thing so I wasn't sure if it was a compiler bug or something else. That being said, I agree with Morwenn—I don't see the point of all those constexpr if we can't even initialize the object... sounds like an half-baked class to me. Maybe I'll post a question to see if someone knows where it's heading to.

Comment: @ChristopherC It is possible though that completely removing the part about "shall be a literal type" is an oversight. I just confirmed that clang++ trunk and g++ trunk both *still* require that the class is a literal type if it has non-static constexpr member functions. (So that's either a bug in both compilers, or something wrong with the Standard.) -- I have also no idea what constexpr member functions on non-literal types could be good for.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out! I've posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496004/why-isnt-stdinitializer-list-defined-as-a-literal-type), let's see.