# Why isn't `std::initializer_list` defined as a literal type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, initializer-list, constexpr

This is a follow-up of this question: [Is it legal to declare a constexpr initializer_list object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063123/is-it-legal-to-declare-a-constexpr-initializer-list-object).

Since C++14, the `std::initializer_list` class has all of its methods marked with `constexpr`. It seems natural to be able to initialize an instance by doing 
`constexpr std::initializer_list<int> list = {1, 2, 3};` 
but Clang 3.5 complains about `list` not being initialized by a constant expression. 
[As dyp pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063123/is-it-legal-to-declare-a-constexpr-initializer-list-object#comment43416424_16067393), any requirement for `std::initializer_list` to be a literal type seem to have vanished from the specs.

What's the point of having a class fully defined as constexpr if we can't even initialize it as such? Is it an oversight in the standard and will get fixed in the future?

Comment: Richard Smith seems to imply [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/C-11-constexpr-and-initializer-list-td4031078.html) that `std::initializer_list` has been made a literal type. However, I cannot find such a requirement in the Standard. A second question, which I've posted on a comment to my question linked above, is *"May constexpr non-static member functions be declared as members of non-literal types?"*, see [CWG DR 1684](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1684)

Comment: This is weird, clang++ compiles this when you put it in the global scope: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dab2834181fb8ea4 (This was [clang bug 15117](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15117)) Smells like another compiler bug to me.

Comment: clang++ also accepts it when it is a local static variable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/700cf33e2446b63c

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/aA3BsR4ZuoE/discussion

Comment: I've got difficulties to understand it all—is Richard Smith basically saying that `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> list = {1, 2, 3};` should be legal? And hence it's a compiler bug as you're suspecting?

Comment: I don't quite understand it either. It seems to be implied in the discussion of [this clang bug 15117](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15117), but I cannot deduce it from the Standard (drafts) or Richard Smith's hint at interpretation. See the continuing discussion on the std-discussion mailing list.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/ej8T6Iyl8VM

Comment: "Is it an oversight in the standard and will get fixed in the future?" - True about C++14 in general.

Comment: Just for the record: GCC 4.9.1 is fine with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard committee seems to intend on `initializer_list` being a literal type.  However, it doesn't look like it's an explicit requirement, and seems to be a bug in the standard.

From § 3.9.10.5:

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>   - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>   - - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one *constexpr* constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

From § 18.9.1:

```
namespace std {
  template<class E> class initializer_list {
  public:
    /* code removed */
    constexpr initializer_list() noexcept;
    // No destructor given, so trivial
    /* code removed */
  };
}
```

This satisfies the first and second requirements.

For the third requirement though:

From § 18.9.2 (emphasis mine):

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`. [Note: **A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length** would be obvious representations for `initializer_list`. `initializer_list` is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.
>   —end note]

So there is no requirement for the private members of the implementation of `initializer_list` to be non-volatile literal types; however, because they mention that they believe a pair of pointers or a pointer and a length would be the "obvious representation," they probably didn't consider that someone might put something non-literal in the members of `initializer_list`.

I'd say that it's both a bug in clang and the standard, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I remember shortly after C++11 came out I was creating an initializer_list whose individual members allocated dynamic memory, so they had non-trivial d'tors, therefore the initializer_list has a non-trivial d'tor.  And there was some circumstance, I think I threw while the initializer_list was partially constructed, where the built part didn't get destroyed, causing a memory leak.  I'm sure the compilers have been fixed by now.