# pass constexpr intializer_list as argument in c++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why doesn't this work:

```
constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};
constexpr int my_min = min(ilist);
```

While this does:

```
constexpr int my_min = min({1,2,3,4});
```

I'm basing my code on the constexpr std::min() function as shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and I'm using clang3.5.0 to compiler (g++4.9.1 doesn't seem to be aware of a constexpr std::min()).

I can't make sense of the error I'm getting:

```
clang35 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 test.cpp  -o test;
test.cpp:158:35: error: constexpr variable 'ilist' must be initialized by a constant expression
  constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};
                                  ^       ~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:158:35: note: pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression
test.cpp:158:43: note: temporary created here
  constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};
                                          ^
test.cpp:159:17: error: constexpr variable 'my_min' must be initialized by a constant expression
  constexpr int my_min = min(ilist);
                ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:159:30: note: initializer of 'ilist' is not a constant expression
  constexpr int my_min = min(ilist);
                             ^
test.cpp:159:30: note: in call to 'initializer_list(ilist)'
test.cpp:158:35: note: declared here
  constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496004/why-isnt-stdinitializer-list-defined-as-a-literal-type) (not voting to close because the linked question has no answers). Also relevant is [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/aA3BsR4ZuoE/discussion) (linked in the comments of the dupe).

Comment: You're right, I actually didn't notice that even just defining `constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};` doesn't compile, unless it's global variable.

Comment: You can fix one of the problems by declaring (the local) `ilist` as `static`. The lifetime of the temporary array used to implement the RHS will be extended to static storage duration, which allows taking its address inside a constant expression. It does not fix the second issue, though - and I'm not sure if that's intentional or a bug.

Comment: It seems intentional: `constexpr static int&& i = 42; constexpr int j = i;` does not compile as well. I don't fully understand the reasoning, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your first snippet doesn't compile as opposed to the second one is the point in time at which the underlying array is being created. [dcl.init.list]/5:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an
>   initializer list as if the implementation allocated a **temporary array**
>   **of `N` elements of type `const E`**, where `N` is the number of elements in
>   the initializer list.

Now, when calling `min`, we access elements of that array. However, [expr.const]/7 is inviolable:

[image]

None of the exceptions apply, but note the last bullet point which is applicable in your second example.

Clang is (unsurprisingly) correct, while GCC spuriously accepts your code. The above ruling is also why @dyp's code fails: Performing an l-t-r conversion on `i` is not a constant expression. In particular, (2.7.1) doesn't apply since the temporary isn't `const`.

Answer (score -2):

C++14 is not implemented in full yet in neither g++ nor clang++. In your particular case: g++ STL does not have implemented `template constexpr T min(std::initializer_list ilist);` 
while clang++ does not have constexptr constructor for initializer_list yet.

Comment: [C++14 status for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html). It should be completed with GCC 5.

Comment: The problem is that `constexpr initializer_list<int> ilist = {1,2,3,4};` fails to compile - not anything about `min`