# MSVC fails to compile when using a constexpr initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr, initializer-list

Why does Microsoft Visual C++ fails when compile the following code? :

```
template <typename T>
struct slice
{
    size_t length;
    T *ptr;

    constexpr slice(std::initializer_list<T> list)
        : length(list.size()), ptr(list.begin()) {}
};

static_assert(slice<const int>({ 1, 2, 3 }).length == 3, "!!");
```

The error I get is:

```
1>test.cpp(12): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>         visual studio 14.0\vc\include\initializer_list(50): note: failure was caused by an undefined arithmetic operation
```

The implementation of `initializer_list` has all methods marked `constexpr`, it looks like it should be fine to me... Maybe it's just a compiler issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It is a <del>compiler</del> Standard issue, <del>as your code compiles fine with</del> [gcc 6.3.1](https://godbolt.org/g/LAJROP) and [clang 3.9.1](https://godbolt.org/g/XBGgV7) both compile your code though.

---

<del>In C++11, not one of the methods is marked `constexpr`, and so you can't use it in a `static_assert`.</del>

<del>You have to note that Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have full `constexpr` support. See [the C++ 14 Core Language Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)
 table in the article. It has only the C++11 version of `std::initializer_list` implemented, which doesn't have any `constexpr` functions.</del>

Small update: It looks like a bad wording in the standard can result in a non-constant `std::initializer_list`:

> From § 18.9.2 (emphasis mine):
>
> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`. [Note: **A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length** would be obvious representations for `initializer_list`. `initializer_list` is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.
> —end note]
>
> So there is no requirement for the private members of the implementation of `initializer_list` to be non-volatile literal types; however, because they mention that they believe a pair of pointers or a pointer and a length would be the "obvious representation," they probably didn't consider that someone might put something non-literal in the members of `initializer_list`.

(Shamelessly copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115954/3980929) answer.) It goes a bit more in depth, about why you couldn't use `std::initializer_list` in a `constexpr` context.

This has been "fixed" in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: My VS2015 `<initializer_list>` which it is compiling against does indeed have `constexpr` on all methods, that's why I was surprised it didn't work.

Comment: @ManuEvans That's weird. After investigation I found that the cause is a bad wording in the Standard, which seems to not have been fixed in the implementation of VS 2015. See edit :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 - confirmed.  ' Compiles with VS2017

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @Jeff That's funny, I tried to switch to 2017, but ran into a much bigger issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917099/vs2017-c-compiler-regression

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/719296/sdl-causes-error-c2131-expression-did-not-evaluate.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [Conformance mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019) on, and it will eliminate the compilation errors.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't for me.  However turning off SDL checks works.