# Why is an initializer_list of enum values not considered a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

In the following code (tested locally and on Wandbox):

```
#include <iostream>

enum Types
{
    A, B, C, D
};

void print(std::initializer_list<Types> types)
{
    for (auto type : types)
    {
        std::cout << type << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto const group1 = { A, D };
    print(group1);
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC 15.8.5 fails to compile with:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
note: see usage of '$S1'
```

(all referring to the line containing `constexpr`)

Clang 8 (HEAD) reports:

```
error: constexpr variable 'group1' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto const group1 = { A, D };
                         ^        ~~~~~~~~
note: pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression
note: temporary created here
    constexpr auto const group1 = { A, D };
                                  ^
```

gcc 9 (HEAD) reports:

```
In function 'int main()':
error: 'const std::initializer_list<const Types>{((const Types*)(&<anonymous>)), 2}' is not a constant expression
   18 |     constexpr auto const group1 = { A, D };
      |                                          ^
error: could not convert 'group1' from 'initializer_list<const Types>' to 'initializer_list<Types>'
   19 |     print(group1);
      |           ^~~~~~
      |           |
      |           initializer_list<const Types>
```

Why?

Firstly, they all apparently consider enum-ids to be non-constant, despite them obviously actually being well-known compile-time constant values.

Secondly, MSVC complains about read outside lifetime, but the lifetime of `group1` and its values should extend throughout its usage in `print`.

Thirdly, gcc has a weird const-vs-non-const complaint that I can't make any sense of, since initialiser lists are always const.

Finally, all but gcc will happily compile and run this code without any problems if `constexpr` is removed.  Granted it is not *necessary* in this case, but I can't see any good reason for it not to work.

Meanwhile gcc will only compile and run the code if the parameter type is changed to `std::initializer_list<const Types>` -- and making this change causes it to fail to compile in both MSVC and clang.

(Interestingly: gcc 8, with the parameter type change, does successfully compile and run the code including `constexpr`, where gcc 9 errors out.)

---

FWIW, changing the declaration to this:

```
    constexpr auto const group1 = std::array<Types, 2>{ A, D };
```

Does compile and run on all three compilers.  So it is probably the `initializer_list` itself that is misbehaving rather than the enum values.  But the syntax is more annoying.  (It's slightly less annoying with a suitable `make_array` implementation, but I still don't see why the original isn't valid.)

---

```
    constexpr auto const group1 = std::array{ A, D };
```

Also works, thanks to C++17 template induction.  Though now `print` can't take an `initializer_list`; it has to be templated on a generic container/iterator concept, which is inconvenient.

Comment: I like the question, I wonder if it is a bug (can be logged on the trackers of the compilers?). Just for curiousity, how does it behave with Enum-class?

Comment: Enum-class behaves exactly the same, except that inside `print` you need an explicit cast to `int`, since the implicit conversion is disabled.

Comment: Even without the enums (just plain int's), I get "expression did not evaluate to a constant" in VS 2019, whereas GCC 10 and clang 10 compile the following fine:

`#include <initializer_list>
constexpr static std::initializer_list<int> a = {1, 2};`

Answer (score 11):

When you initialize a `std::initializer_list` it happens like this:

> **[dcl.init.list]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#5) An object of type std​::​initializer_­list is constructed
>   from an initializer list **as if the implementation generated and
>   materialized a prvalue of type “array of N const E”**, where N is the
>   number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array
>   is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer
>   list, and the std​::​initializer_­list object is constructed to
>   refer to that array. [ *Note*: A constructor or conversion function
>   selected for the copy shall be accessible in the context of the
>   initializer list.  — *end note* ] If a narrowing conversion is required
>   to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.
>   [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   X(std::initializer_list<double> v);
> };
> X x{ 1,2,3 };
> ```
>
> The initialization will be implemented in a way roughly equivalent to
>   this:
>
> ```
> const double __a[3] = {double{1}, double{2}, double{3}};
> X x(std::initializer_list<double>(__a, __a+3));
> ```
>
> assuming that the implementation can construct an initializer_­list
>   object with a pair of pointers.  — *end example* ]

How that temporary array gets used to initialize the `std::initializer_list` is what determines if the `initializer_list` is initialized with a constant expression. Ultimately, according to example (despite being non-normative), that initialization is going to take the address of the array, or its first element, which will produce a value of a pointer type. And that is not a valid constant expression.

> **[expr.const]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5) A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant
>   expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
>   expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>     constant expression,
> - **if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such
>     an object ([expr.add]), the address of a function, or a null pointer
>     value, and**
> - if the value is an object of class or array type, each subobject satisfies these constraints for the value.
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an
>   object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary
>   object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above
>   constraints, or it is a function.

If the array was however a static object, then that initializer would constitute a valid constant expression that can be used to initialize a `constexpr` object. Since `std::initializer_list` has an effect of lifetime extension on that temporary by [[dcl.init.list]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#6), when you [declare `group1` as a static object](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf01b30e9c0a046b), clang and gcc seem allocate the array as a static object too, which makes the initialization's well-formedness subject only to whether or not `std::initializer_list` is a literal type and the constructor being used is `constexpr`.

Ultimately, it's all a bit murky.

Answer (score 7):

It appears `std::initializer_list` does not yet (in C++17) fulfill the requirements of [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) (which is a requirement the type of a [`constexpr` variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) has to satisfy).

A discussion on whether it does so in C++14 is found in this post: [Why isn't `std::initializer_list` defined as a literal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496004/why-isnt-stdinitializer-list-defined-as-a-literal-type)
which itself was a followup to the post discussing [Is it legal to declare a `constexpr initializer_list` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063123/is-it-legal-to-declare-a-constexpr-initializer-list-object)

I compared the citations provided in the C++14 related post (of the C++14 standard) to the final working draft (of the C++17 standard) and they are the same.
So there is no explicit requirement that  `std::initializer_list` should be a literal type.

Citations from the final working draft of C++17 (n4659):

[[basic.types]/10.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#10.5)

> (10.5) a possibly cv-qualified class type (Clause 12) that has all of the
>   following properties:
>   (10.5.1) — it has a trivial destructor,
>   (10.5.2) — it is either a closure type (8.1.5.1), an aggregate type (11.6.1),
>   or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template
>   (possibly inherited (10.3.3) from a base class) that is not a copy or
>   move constructor,
>   (10.5.3) — if it is a union, at least one of its non-static data members is of non-volatile literal type, and
>   (10.5.4)  — if it is not a union, all of its non-static data members and base
>   classes **are of non-volatile literal types**.

[[initializer_list.syn]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/initializer_list.syn#1)

> 1. An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of objects of type const E. [ Note:**A pair of pointers or a pointer** plus a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list. initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 11.6.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements. —end note ]

That is the reason why it is not legal to declare a `constexpr initializer_list` object.

Comment: Then how is it that the `std::array`, which takes an `initializer_list` constructor parameter, *does* satisfy being a `constexpr`?  Why is it that the compiler can't similarly construct a backing array and an `initializer_list` to it as `constexpr`?

Comment: I suppose technically that's aggregate initialisation, rather than actually using an `initializer_list` constructor.  But it's still weird that this is treated differently.

Comment: @Miral `std::array` does not take an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: I did say that.  But aggregate initialization and an `initializer_list` constructor are supposed to be equivalent.