# Best way to pass compile-time list of values to function?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, compile-time

I'm trying to find the best way to pass a compile-time list of values to a utility function, as an exercise based on a real use case. This list will be subjected to some series of operations and the resulting value will be used in another operation in runtime. Below are some solutions I found, simplified to MWEs.

Of course, the operations are much more complex in the real use case, hence the need for these utility functions.

### Solution 1: Parameter pack

```
template <int number>
constexpr int sum() {
    return number;
}

template <int number, int next, int... rest>
constexpr int sum() {
    return number + sum<next, rest...>();
}

//API:

template <int... numbers>
inline void add(int& target) {
    target += sum<numbers...>();
}
...
int number = 0;
add<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(number);
```

**Pros**:

- Clean API
- Needs only c++14

**Cons**:

- Clunky implementation with recursion, painful to design and read when operations are complex

### Solution 2: `std::array`

```
template <size_t N, std::array<int, N> numbers>
constexpr int sum() {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int number : numbers)
        ret += number;
    return ret;
}

//API:

template <size_t N, std::array<int, N> numbers>
inline void add(int& target) {
    target += sum<N, numbers>();
}
...
int number = 0;
add<5, std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>(number);
```

**Pros**:

- Clean and readable implementation, easy to design no matter the complexity of operations

**Cons**:

- Super clunky API, size of list must be specified separately
- Needs c++20 to be able to pass inline `std::array` as non-type template parameter

### Solution 3: `std::array` wrapper

```
template <size_t N>
struct IntArray {
    constexpr IntArray(std::array<int, N> arr_) : arr(arr_) {}
    const std::array<int, N> arr;
};

template <IntArray numbers>
constexpr int sum() {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int number : numbers.arr)
        ret += number;
    return ret;
}

//API:

template <IntArray numbers>
inline void add(int& target) {
    target += sum<numbers>();
}
...
int target = 0;
add<IntArray<5>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})>(target);
```

**Pros**:

- Clean and readable implementation, easy to design no matter the complexity of operations

**Cons**:

- (Arguably) less but still clunky API, size of list must be specified separately
- Needs c++20 to be able to pass inline `IntArray` as non-type template parameter, and also to be able to omit the `IntArray` template parameter value in at least the function definitions

### Solution 4: `std::initializer_list`

```
template <std::initializer_list<int> numbers>
constexpr int sum() {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int number : numbers)
        ret += number;
    return ret;
}

template <std::initializer_list<int> numbers>
inline void add(int& target) {
    target += sum<numbers>();
}
...
int target = 0;
add<{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>(target);
```

**Pros**:

- Clean and readable implementation, easy to design no matter the complexity of operations
- Clean, usable and readable API

**Cons**:

- Doesn't actually compile (g++ 10.3.0 with `gnu++2a`): `‘std::initializer_list<int>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural`

I have no idea what "not structural" means to be very honest. I'm actually surprised and disappointed by the fact that this approach doesn't work, given that `std::initializer_list` is apparently fully `constexpr` and `std::array` works in the same situation. There seems to be a bug in the standard about the literalness of `std::initializer_list` though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115954/1525238 In any case, I do see this as a missed opportunity for some really cool compile-time wizardry.

### The question:

Can you suggest any way to improve the solutions above in any way possible, or suggest other solutions? Ideally the "best" solution would combine all of API and implementation cleanliness and readability, while requiring as low c++ standard as possible.

Comment: You need to define "best", otherwise this is opinion-based.

Comment: In (1), you can either use fold-expressions to avoid recursion, or initialize an array with the pack and iterate over it normally.

Comment: `std::initializer_list<T>` is definitely not usable as a non-type template parameter now (and likely never will be), and if it were, it probably wouldn't do what you'd expect anyway, since template equivalence isn't just `==`. So (4) is clearly not a solution.

Comment: @Barry care to elaborate? What's semantically the difference between `initializer_list` and `array` in this case? Especially the term "not structural" doesn't mean anything to me at this point.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür `array` owns its data, `initializer_list` does not. "structural" is the language term for "usable as a non-type template parameter, and is defined [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#def:type,structural)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HolyBlackCat for suggesting to initialize a `std::array` from the pack, which I didn't know was possible:

```
template <int... numbers>
constexpr int sum() {
    std::array<int, sizeof...(numbers)> arr = {numbers...};
    int ret = 0;
    for(int number : arr)
        ret += number;
    return ret;
}

//API:

template <int... numbers>
inline void add(int& target) {
    target += sum<numbers...>();
}
...
int number = 0;
add<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(number);
```

This makes the implementation much cleaner. Requires c++17.

Comment: There is no need to use `std::array` in the implementation of sum, it is much simpler to use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) like `return (numbers + ... + 0)`;