# Crash when using simple constexpr array of initializer_list on MSVC (fine on gcc and clang)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr

Here is some simple program (reduced version when I was writing data for some unit tests):

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

constexpr std::initializer_list<std::string_view> data[] {
    {},
    {
        "aa"sv,
        "bb"sv,
    },
    {
        "cc"sv,
        "dd"sv,
        "ee"sv,
    },
};

std::vector<std::string> banHashesDataGenerator(size_t index)
{
    if (index >= std::size(data)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument { "index out of range" };
    }
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (auto& item : data[index]) {
        result.emplace_back(std::string { item });
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto& x : banHashesDataGenerator(1)) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run compile it on Win10 with MSVC 19.38.33133 I see crash (with and without address sanitizer enabled).

```
C:\Users\marek r\Downloads>cl /std:c++20 /EHcs bug.cpp /fsanitize=address /Zi
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33133 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bug.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.38.33133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:bug.exe
/InferAsanLibs
/debug
bug.obj

C:\Users\marek r\Downloads>bug.exe
=================================================================
==21384==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: access-violation on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7ff62bc718e1 bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x008189cff9a0 T0)
==21384==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==21384==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7ff62bc718e0 in std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>><class std::basic_string_view<char, struct std::char_traits<char>>, 0>(class std::basic_string_view<char, struct std::char_traits<char>> const &, class std::allocator<char> const &) (C:\Users\marek r\Downloads\bug.exe+0x1400018e0)
    #1 0x7ff62bc7140d in banHashesDataGenerator(unsigned __int64) (C:\Users\marek r\Downloads\bug.exe+0x14000140d)
    #2 0x7ff62bc715a8 in main (C:\Users\marek r\Downloads\bug.exe+0x1400015a8)
    #3 0x7ff62bcb9bbb in invoke_main D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
    #4 0x7ff62bcb9bbb in __scrt_common_main_seh D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
    #5 0x7ffd2b8f7343  (C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017343)
    #6 0x7ffd2cba26b0  (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x1800526b0)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: access-violation (C:\Users\marek r\Downloads\bug.exe+0x1400018e0) in std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>><class std::basic_string_view<char, struct std::char_traits<char>>, 0>(class std::basic_string_view<char, struct std::char_traits<char>> const &, class std::allocator<char> const &)
==21384==ABORTING

C:\Users\marek r\Downloads>cl /std:c++20 /EHcs bug.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33133 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bug.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.38.33133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:bug.exe
bug.obj

C:\Users\marek r\Downloads>bug.exe

CRASH
```

It is [fine on gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TKxrjWW95).

Is this some known bug of MSVC? Is there some nice workaround on this issue (i prefer to have those `constexpr` test data). Or maybe I've missed something and my code is simply invalid?

Comment: Might have something to do with `initializer_list`, I'm not sure this is legal. Remember that constructing a `std::initializer_list` from a braced list [creates a temporary object](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#5), that lives until the end of the full expression. The standard also says that `std::initializer_list` extends the lifetime of that temporary, but I'm unsure if that works when it's an array element.

Comment: I would get rid of `initializer_list`, and place each sub-array into its own global variable.

Comment: Adding explicitly `std::initializer_list<std::string_view>` to each array item, fixed crash :/.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in my test data, size of each item changes, that is why I used `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant you can have individual array variables of different sizes, and then combine then into e.g. an array of spans.